# Variadic templates and functions' pointers: what compiler is right?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, variadic-templates

<sub>I've not been able to find a better title, but feel free to modify it if you have the right idea. As it is, it's better than *GCC vs clang* anyway.</sub>

---

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong in this code:

```
template <typename... T>
struct S;

template <typename T, typename... U>
struct S<T, U...>: S<U...> {
    using S<U...>::f;

    template<void(*F)(const T &)>
    void f() { }
};

template<>
struct S<> {
    void f();
};

template<typename... T>
struct R: S<T...> {
    using S<T...>::f;

    template<typename U, void(*F)(const U &)>
    void g() {
        this->template f<F>();
    }
};

void h(const double &) { }

int main() {
    R<int, double> r;
    r.g<double, h>();
}
```

It compiles with *GCC 4.9* (see [here](https://godbolt.org/g/LvMSfI)), but it doesn't compile with *clang 3.8.0* (see [here](https://godbolt.org/g/yoTWR3)).

Which compiler is right and why?
Moreover, what could I do to see the code compiling with both the compilers?

Comment: It's strange (still testing) and for now i can suggest add flag "variadic-templates" to the question.

Comment: It appears that ICC also fails to compile this:https://godbolt.org/g/N67e2z

Comment: Maybe related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629839/c-candidate-template-ignored-invalid-explicitly-specified-argument-for-templ) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872039/invalid-explicitly-specified-argument-in-clang-but-successful-compilation-in-gcc)?

Comment: @Nathan AFAIK icc13.0 is quite old and does not implements all of C++11 standard,

Comment: I have found similar [problem with variadic here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420828/another-bug-in-g-clang-c-templates-are-fun) The template member lookup differs for normal template and variadic template and that might be same for you.

Comment: I actually think that gcc is correct on this one.

Comment: @callyalater Despite what Barry said? Feel free to add your own answer, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @skypjack I'm working on it...

Comment: @skypjack see my edit...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that clang is correct here and this is a gcc bug. First, let's start with a simplified example:

```
struct U {
    template<int > void foo() { }
};

struct X : U {
    using U::foo;
    template<void* > void foo() { }
};

int main() {
    X{}.foo<1>(); // gcc ok, clang error
}
```

From [[namespace.udecl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.namespace#namespace.udecl-15):

> When a *using-declaration* brings declarations from a base class into a derived class, member functions and
>   member function templates in the derived class override and/or hide member functions and member function
>   templates with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (if any) in a
>   base class (rather than conflicting). Such hidden or overridden declarations are excluded from the set of
>   declarations introduced by the *using-declaration*.

`U::foo` and `X::foo` have the same name, parameter-type-list (none<sup>†</sup>), cv-qualification (none), and ref qualifier (none). Hence, `X::foo` **hides** `U::foo` rather than overloading it and we're definitely passing the wrong type into `X::foo`.

Simply overloading on different function pointer types (rather than taking them as template parameters) works fine:

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
struct S<T, U...> : S<U...> {
    using S<U...>::f;

    void f(void (*F)(const T&)) { }
};
```

Or if you really need the function pointers as template arguments, could still overload by wrap them in a tag type:

```
template <class T>
using fptr = void(*)(const T&);

template <class T, fptr<T> F>
using func_constant = std::integral_constant<fptr<T>, F>;
```

and propagate that through:

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
struct S<T, U...>: S<U...> {
    using S<U...>::f;

    template <fptr<T> F>
    void f(func_constant<T, F> ) { }
};
```

and:

```
template <class U, fptr<U> F>
void g() {
    this->f(func_constant<U, F>{});
}
```

<sup>†</sup>The definition of [parameter-type-list](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5) doesn't mention template parameters.

Comment: But parameter-type-list does mention parameter packs which come from the template declaration. So, doesn't that mean that the templates would be considered in function resolution for overloading vs hiding?

Comment: @callyalater But a parameter pack is still a parameter. A template argument isn't.

Comment: @Barry A kind of tag dispatching, right? I thought the same, but I was wondering if that's the most suitable solution. Thank you for the detailed response (as usual, really appreciated).

Answer (score 3):

After @barry - changing the definition of `f` in `S` specialization to:

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
struct S<T, U...>: S<U...> {
    using S<U...>::f;


    template<void(*F)(const T &)>
    void f(T *= nullptr) { }
};
```

Makes also clang working with your code.

**Edit:**

To make the code even simpler you could change the specializations to:

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
struct S<T, U...>: S<T>, S<U...> {
};

template<typename T>
struct S<T> {
    template<void(*F)(const T &)>
    void f() { }
}
```

And then invoke your `f` method in `g` using:

```
S<U>::template f<F>();
```

Using this option you can go a step further and as @barry suggested use a tag dispatching but in template parameter rather than as a paramter of a function:

```
template <typename... T>
struct S;

template <typename T>
struct footag { };

template <typename T, typename... U>
struct S<T, U...>: S<footag<T>>, S<U...> {
};

template<typename T>
struct S<T>:S<footag<T>> {
};

template<typename T>
struct S<footag<T>> {
    template <void (*F)(const T&)>
    void f() { }
};

template<typename V, typename... T>
struct R: S<V, T...> {
    template<typename U, void(*F)(const U &)>
    void g() {
        S<footag<U>>::template f<F>();
    }
};

void h(const float &) { }

int main() {
    R<int, float, double> r;
    r.g<float, h>();
}
```

Comment: Well, `nullptr` instead of `NULL` would be more *C++11*-ish, wouldn't it?

Comment: I guess to rely on tag dispatching is a nicer solution. What you are proposing looks more like a mixin based approach, but it is not what I'm looking for (do not misunderstand, I really like the mixin, but this is not the problem for which I'd use them). Does it make sense?

Comment: @skypjack You're right but I think its kind of both - mixin and tag dispatching. I do not suggest that it is better solution, just an alternative approach that may be taken and worth to be considered...

Comment: Absolutely, it's worth it, that's why I spent a bit of time to give you a feedback. That's my way of saying *thank you*!! :-)

Comment: @skypjack Well, making edit was much as saying *interesting question!* so we're even ;-)